# If the probability of stock XYZ going up on any one day is 50%. What is the probability that it goes up exactly 4 out of 6 days?

Tags: statistics, combinations, probability

I'm having trouble answering these. It has been awhile for me and am not sure where to start.

If the probability of stock XYZ going up on any one day is 50%. What is the probability that it goes up exactly 4 out of 6 days?

If the probability of stock XYZ going down on any one day is 30%. What is the probability that it goes down exactly 3 out of 6 days

I will give you my best guess at B. Which Might answer A.

B - 
6C3 * .3^3 * .7^3 = 18.52%

A - 
6C4 * .5^4*.5^2 = 23.4%?

But again I have no idea

Comment: I will give you my best guess at B. Which Might answer A.

B - 
6C3 * .3^3 * .7^3 = 18.52%

A - 
6C4 * .5^4*.5^2 = 23.4%?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability / mathematics, not programming or software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly easy to *test* your calculations, especially for the first case where the probability is exactly 50%. Work out *all* the possibilities over the time frame:

```
  1      2      3      4      5      6
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
not-up not-up not-up not-up not-up not-up
not-up not-up not-up not-up not-up     up
not-up not-up not-up not-up     up not-up
not-up not-up not-up not-up     up     up
:
    up     up     up     up     up not-up
    up     up     up     up     up     up
```

Now work out how many of those have *exactly* four `up` events. Divide that by the total and there you have, it, the chance of what you're after (between zero and one inclusive, multiply by a hundred to get the percentage, obviously).

Since this is a programming site rather than a math/combinatorics/probability site, here's some sample (and fairly primitive) Python code that can work it out for you:

```
outcomes = ['F','T']
total = 0
selection = 0
for day1 in outcomes:
  for day2 in outcomes:
    for day3 in outcomes:
      for day4 in outcomes:
        for day5 in outcomes:
          for day6 in outcomes:
            total += 1
            trues = 0
            if day1 == 'T': trues += 1
            if day2 == 'T': trues += 1
            if day3 == 'T': trues += 1
            if day4 == 'T': trues += 1
            if day5 == 'T': trues += 1
            if day6 == 'T': trues += 1
            if trues == 4: selection += 1
print('Probability is', selections, '/', total, 'or', 100 * selections / total, '%')
```

That shows `15/64, 23.4375%`, matching what you calculated.

The second part is a little more complicated but can be done just by modifying the outcomes for a 30%/day possibility, and checking for three days rather than four:

```
outcomes = ['T', 'T', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'F']
:
if trues == 3: selections += 1
```

That gives `185220/1000000, 18.522%` which again matches your calculation.

Comment: Sweet. That helps. I used the py code and actually got the same answer as on my guess. :) Thank you

Comment: @scarebear, feel free to upvote and/or accept if the answer is correct. That way, the better answers rise to the top of the pile.

Comment: I can't. I do not have enough clout with Stackexchange to upvote anything. Sorry.

Comment: @scarebear, you can *always* accept answers to your questions, provided they fix your problem. It's the green tick mark to the left of the answer. You'll have to wait until you ask some more good questions before you can vote (15 rep to vote up, 125 to vote down).